# Mongoose projection on nested field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to do a projection upon a nested field but it's retrieving the whole field instead of the nested `type` attribute:

Nested field in User document:

[image]

```
const type=await User.findOne({email: enteredEmail}).select({_id:0, 'accountType.type':1})
console.log(type)
```

Output:

```
{ accountType: { type: 'social_account' } }
```

How to modify query to retrieve: `'social_account'` instead of the whole AccountType attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation [`$project`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#project-aggregation) operator to project field from embed document to top-level document.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    accountType: {
        type: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
});
const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        await User.collection.drop();
        // seed
        await User.create({ email: 'nick@gmail.com', accountType: { type: 'social_account' } });

        //test
        const r = await User.aggregate()
            .match({ email: 'nick@gmail.com' })
            .project({ type: '$accountType.type', email: 1, _id: 0 })
            .exec();
        console.log(r);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Debug logs:

```
Mongoose: users.drop()
Mongoose: users.insertOne({ email: 'nick@gmail.com', accountType: { type: 'social_account' }, _id: ObjectId("649c2b69fdb39ffcc3c31854"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: users.aggregate([ { '$match': { email: 'nick@gmail.com' } }, { '$project': { type: '$accountType.type', email: 1, _id: 0 } }], {})
[ { email: 'nick@gmail.com', type: 'social_account' } ]
```

Comment: I'm getting `[ { type: 'social_account' } ]`. I guess I could use `console.log(type[0].type)` but is there a way to output result without the `[]` brackets?

Comment: @D.Rattansingh The aggeration results always be an array, just use `result[0]` to pick the first object. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483330/node-js-how-to-return-object-in-query-aggregation and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46599310/6463558